# How the MOSFETs driven by a six winding transformer

Tags: mosfet, transformer

I have a 6 winding transformer of 1:1:1:1:1:1 as shown in figure. And connected to V1 and V2 MOSFETs. DRV and DRVGND are fed from a HCPL 3120 driver.
[image]
My questions are 
1) Is it acting like a 1:2 transformer for mosfets? 
2) Why do we fed from one terminal of primary and one terminal of secondary? (Actually I asked a question on 6 winding transformer previously just for information.But I am not understanding why this one is  for mosfets. Sorry for asking again on this transformer)

Comment: Please draw the rest of the circuit too. We are not mind readers.

Comment: no need to draw the circuit. it just a full bridge inverter. what i shown in above figure is half of the full bridge. it is same to the second half.

Comment: No need? If you have a full understanding of the circuit, that's fine, but you are asking a question so you need to provide more information. If you need to explain to Andy below how it's connected, this should be your clue that you need to draw a schematic.

Comment: This is my circuit http://imgur.com/Q9BtxjP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have 6 windings and it is probably best to forget about such concepts as "primary" and "secondary" and regard all windings as equal to each other. Now, if you took the time to draw it out sensibly you would find that, in effect, you have three windings and all of them are 1:1:1: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJY7QZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As for the context in which the transformer is used, that is up to you to decide. However, now that the transformer wiring is simplified, it's clear to me that DRV and DRVGND receive a signal to drive two isolated MOSFETs (connected to their respective gate/source connections on the other windings). The signals that feed the two MOSFETs are inverted with respect to each other.

Comment: actually this is one side of a full bridge inverter as shown in this circuit http://imgur.com/Q9BtxjP could you please tell me this transformer is just for isolation purpose or for phase shifting purpose

Comment: @AshokKumar. The transformer is for both isolation and to invert one mosfet drive signal with respect to the other - I can't put dot notation on the schematic in my answer but if you follow the dots on your original question it will become clear. Maybe I can put this on the schematic using text? Yes I can!!!

Comment: So here i no need to add external phase shifting circuit right? this transformer itself act as a phase shifter

Comment: @AshokKumar the transformer will drive one mosfet while the other one is turned off and then reverse that process so, there is no need to provide phase shifting or inversion because it is inherent due to the dot notation on the transformer windings. When DRV is positive (with respect to DRVGND) MOSFET 2 will be activated and when DRV is negative (with respect to DRVGND), MOSFET 1 will be activated.

Comment: Here i am using HCPL3120 gate driver with the input of 5V square wave. I am connecting +15V to Vcc and common to Vee of this gate driver to get 15V as a gate pulse (I am using RT-50C. It is a +- 15V DC supply). And what happens if i connect Vcc to +15V and Vee to -15V of RT-50C.

Comment: i can't follow your circuit description so please post a picture. You also seem to be diverting away from your original question.

Comment: Its not a diverting question, i am thinking that this hcpl driver will do the inversion/phase shifting.But i got the answer for that question. Any way thank you for your answer, at last i got clear idea about that circuit.

Answer (score 0):

It is a 1:1:1 transformer like Andy aka has stated .The main reason for those double windings which complicates things is Leakage inductance.Most gate drive systems for mosfets use a square wave.Leakage inductance will resonate with the gate capacitance making the peaks of the squarewave ring .Leakage inductance also slows the turn on and turn off transitions which is generally undesirable.Partitioning a winding is a well known way of reducing leakage inductance .In your example the winding is split in two .This represents a commonsense balance between transformer complexity and gate drive performance.

Comment: You are saying that gate drive systems for mosfets uses square wave, is this square wave converted into gate pulse or  this square wave is doing operation of turning ON and OFF for mosfet?

Comment: please clarify my doubt